# Does sonar-runner support C# analysis on sonarqube 5 with C# 4.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Is it possible to analyze C# project using Sonar-runner with sonar-c#-plugin-4.2. I saw the MSBuild SonarQube Runner to be used for C# analysis on the documentation.

Does sonar-runner support C# analysis on sonarqube 5 with C# 4.2

Comment: I guess the real question is: Why can't you use the MSBuild SonarQube Runner?

Answer (score 0):

The use of the sonar-runner is no longer supported to analyze C# projects. Indeed, analysis through the MSBuild SonarQube Runner will be of much higher quality because it fully integrates with MSBuild and knows everything about your project, and at the same time also much easier to setup, again because most manual configuration required before is now obtained through MSBuild itself.

Answer (score 0):

At least I managed to run the analysis with the sonar-runner. I consider the new begin-build-end workflow with MSBuild SonarQube Runner a bit complicated while using Jenkins and having plenty of existing scripts in play at least. Or I could not get it working due to slightly TFS-oriented documentation with Visual Studio command prompt being also involved.

I finally, after intensive googling, got the analysis running with my Visual Studio Pro + Jenkins + OpenCover + Mstest + Nunit combination by defining below properties in Invoke Standalone SonarCube Analysis in Jenkins job. I still do not know how to separate integration tests from unit tests. It does not say anywhere is this even supported for C# projects.

Workflow is that I first build everything, then run OpenCover to collect results with coverage and then invoke the runner. The below properties can of course be as file in the root folder of the project as well, but in my initial proof of concept I set these in Jenkins plugin.

```
sonar.projectName=projectname
sonar.projectKey=key
sonar.ProjectVersion=1.1
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true 
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sources=.
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=code.sln
#not sure if the line below is correct or relevant...
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*Test
#two frameworks producing tests.
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=relativepath/results.trx
sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=relativepath/testresults.xml
sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=1.xml,2.xml
```